# C++ Cannot open lib file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, linker

I'm using Microsoft Visual studio 2013.
Trying to import DevIL library to load image files i'm getting LNK1104 error: Cannot open file "IL/devil.lib"

My Source.h file which include DevIL libs in Project/Sources directory while the DevIL libs in Project/Sources/IL directory. Here is my code

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "IL/devil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "IL/ilu.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "IL/ilut.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: As always when using relative paths: ask yourself, *is it valid*?

Comment: see [Relative path with #pragma comment(lib)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16280100/33499)

Comment: Okay I fix it. Now i'm getting Error Dialog DevIL.dll is missing from your computer but the dll is in the same folder as libs

Comment: @hak_android put the .dll in the same folder as the executable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to remove the directory, and use the linker settings to specify the directory;

```
#pragma comment(lib, "devil.lib")
```

or you can use a [hackish way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16280100/33499) using `__FILE__`:

```
#pragma comment(lib, __FILE__"\\..\\IL\\devil.lib")
```

Answer (score 10):

You just need to add your path lib file to Additional Library Directories in VS. Right click on your project, select Properties/Linker/General, then aim to your lib file in Additional Library Directories path.

[image: Follow this below picture.]